# How to assign values to class objects in a 2D array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a `MapTile` class which holds a tile sprite and the tile's attribute. I want to create a 2D array which holds for example 100 tiles in a 10x10 grid. I have drawn a tile map using a plain old 2D array holding only the tile sprite and that worked fine. However, now when I assign a tile sprite to the 2D Array named `mapData` containing `MapTile` classes and using `mapData[i][j].tileSprite = tileNum`, every element in the column is assigned the `tileNum` value. I have tried everything I could think of to get this to work. I am a C++ programmer new to Ruby.

```
class MapTile
attr_accessor :tileSprite, :attribute

    def initialize(sprite, attr)
    @tileSprite = sprite
    @attribute = attr
    end 

    def tileSprite
        @tileSprite
    end

    def attribute
        @attribute
    end

end



def array2D(width,height)
  a = Array.new(width, MapTile.new(123,0))
  a.map! { Array.new(height, MapTile.new(123,0)) }
  return a
end


@mapData = array2D(@mapSize,@mapSize)

mapData[1][j].tileSprite = tileNum  #Now every tileSprite in column 1 is tileNum
```

*Solution*

Changed the array2D method to

```
def array2D(width,height)
a = Array.new(width) { MapTile.new(10,0)}
a.map! { Array.new(height) { MapTile.new(10,0) } }
return a
end
```

Thanks Michael!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same object for each array element. Try `Array.new(width) { MapTile.new(123,0) }` instead.

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-new):

```
# only one copy of the object is created 
a = Array.new(2, Hash.new)

# here multiple copies are created 
a = Array.new(2) { Hash.new }
```

BTW: There are some things in your code that are rather unidiomatic Ruby, you may want to run that by the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Michael! I edited the question to reflect the changes, your solution worked. And I will run my code by the Code Review Stack Exchange. Looks like a great site! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ehm Spencer, you're suposed to accept the answer that worked for you.